# Best Practice: Unit testing a method that takes in a Socket as an argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sockets

I trying to unit test a class of methods that take in a Socket object to which they both read and write.  I'm wondering, what is the best way to go about this?  I am working in a team (this is a university project) and am only responsible for this (java) class, so completely refactoring the code isn't really an option.

Is there any sort of mock socket available, like a "Mocket", or something? How would you approach this problem?

As I mentioned, I am a university student, so I am looking forward to learning from the wisdom of the forum.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: MДΓΓ БДLL, how would I do that?  Would you mind posting a link?

Answer (score 2):

To make your code testable, classes that depend on `Socket` should depend on socket's abstraction - for example, simple interface that exposes methods you use (like read and write). Your application will use wrapper around real `Socket` class, yet in unit test you will be able to use mock (check [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) for this).

Consider:

```
public interface ISocket
{
    byte[] read();
    int write(byte[] content);
}

public class SocketWrapper : ISocket
{
    // read and write methods simply delegate work to real socket
}

public class ClassToTest
{
    private ISocket socket;

    public ClassToTest(ISocket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

Now in your unit test you can create mock of `ISocket` and pass it to `ClassToTest` constructor. This way, you isolate unit test from its dependencies.

Comment: +1 but in my opinion the interface should be client and not a socket, which will give more abstraction in this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to declare the socket interface first like:

```
public interface IClient{
 bool connect(...);
 bool disconnect(...);
 bool sendData(...);
}
```

After that create a class which implements the interface. This class will contain a Socket.

In your class where you need to test the code you will pass the interface of the client and not a concrete implementation. In this way:
1) you will be able to exchange your system's behavior without any change in your tested class.
2) you will be able to mock your client with any implementation you need, so you will test the code much easily than by using the socket as argument.

Answer (score 0):

All good suggestions, thank you!  The trouble was, I had to preserve the interface/api that I was given, so as not to break the autograder.

What I did instead was to just subclass the Socket class (I did end up calling my subclass Mocket) and then override the getInputStream and getOutputStream methods.  This allowed me to control the flow of data in and out of the methods, and was sufficient for testing.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Using that approach, you ended creating a dependency with the real `Socket` in your test code. The `Mocket` class, created to be used in tests, will depende on the `Socket` class, code that's not yours to test.

When you do test your code, you have to keep the boundaries, and guarantee you only test your code, and no one else's code.

@jimmy_keen was a good answer.